# Function of a sequence, how to answer these types of questions.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't quite get this idea of taking the function of a sequence, and what it implies.

The questions I am getting go a bit like this;

Given a sequence $s_n$ that converges to some $a$ as $n$ gets bigger, what do we know about the limit of $f(s_n)$ as n gets bigger given that $f$ is continuous in some $x_1$ and has $f(x_1) = y_1$

Here's an example. $s_n$ converges to 1. $f$ is continuous on $x=2$ and $f(2) = 1$. We conclude that $f(s_n^2 + s_n)$ converges to 1. (This is the correct answer in a multiple choice test asking "what we know for sure").

Why? This makes zero sense to me. Must've not been in class the day this was thought, and can't seem to find anything in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a continuous function at $x_1$ (with $f(x_1)=y_1$) then for any convergence sequence $(a_n)$ with limit $x_1$  you have that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n)=f(\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n)=f(x_1)=y_1.$$

In your example $s_n\to 1$ from where $a_n=s_n^2+s_n\to 2.$ Now you can use continuity at $x=2$ to get that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n)=f(\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n)=f(2)=1.$$

In general, you can't say anything about $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(s_n)$ if $s_n\to a$ and you only know the continuity of $f$ at some point $x_1\ne a.$ But, if you have a expression for $x_1$ in terms of $a,$ say $x_1=a^3-3a^2+a-1,$ then you have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(s_n^3-3s_n^2+s_n-1)=f(\lim_{n\to \infty} (s_n^3-3s_n^2+s_n-1))=f(x_1)=y_1.$$